# Java SHA-256 Hash Not Matching Expected Output

Tags: java, cryptography, sha, cryptocurrency

I'm having an issue with a project involving a basic cryptocurrency. One of the requirements is to check the hash of a previous line against the hash provided in a file. So essentially, you will compute the SHA-256 hash of the previous line, compare to the hash provided, and throw an exception if the valid hash was not provided.

I'm getting an error, however, and I've narrowed it down to the actual hashing code. I've verified that the file is being read in correctly, as far as I can tell, but once the method comes that converts the `byte[]` computed hash to the provided hash, it finds them not equivalent and throws an exception. I've been trying to debug but am really not sure where the issue is.

My code is below. Thanks!

```
 if (block_line == null && block_hash == "0")
 {
   return true;         //genesis block, special hash
 }
 //remove new lines and tabs
 block_line = block_line.replaceAll("\\r\\n", "");
 byte[] hash = null;
 byte[] file_hash = block_hash.getBytes();

 try
 {
   //create SHA-256 hash of raw line to ensure following hash is correct
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
   md.update(block_line.getBytes());
   hash = md.digest();
 }
 catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsaex)
 {
   System.err.println("No SHA-256 algorithm found.");
   System.err.println("This generally should not happen...");
   System.exit(1);
 }
 //check if the hash in the file was valid for the line in question
 try
 {
   if (Arrays.equals(hash, file_hash))
   {
     return true;         //file hash is valid
   }
   else
   {
     throw new InvalidDataException(block_hash, 0);
   }
 }
 catch (InvalidDataException ide)
 {
   System.err.println("InvalidDataException: " + ide);
   ide.printStackTrace();
   System.err.println("Quitting...");
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: 1.) Don’t throw an exception and catch it in the same function. 2.) This probably relates to UTF-16 vs UTF-8. 3.) Don’t recreate the message digest harsher every cycle. 4.) Don’t post images of console output.

Comment: Plus you can't compare strings with ==, and you're not removing tabs or single new lines, only CR LF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that the `block_hash` contains an *encoded* digest value in hexadecimals (or possibly base 64). Using `getBytes` you just get the standard encoding of that string: it doesn't decode the hex or base 64. When you compare the byte arrays then the binary `hash` value is compared with the binary `file_hash` containing the *encoded* digest. Therefore the comparison will fail (if just because the digests will be of different sizes).

Next time put in a log statement or `println` statement and print out the hexadecimal hashes so you can compare them by eye.

Comment: that's working thanks! I guess I missed that but that definitely makes sense